# On Blinking button it goes to a light shade

Tags: ios, swift, button

[image]

click a add button in the same page of the blinking button page to select a name from a new page and back to the blinking button page the blinking button is not blinking and is in a light shade.

```
    self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.80, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
        self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 0.2
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    })
```

Comment: Where have you added this code snippet?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad()

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Need to reset `alpha` to 1 in `completion` block -

```
    self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.80, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
        self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 0.2
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 1.0
    })
```

Comment: can you attach recorded `gif` of your current Screen? so that I can dig into it.